# XSLT generate-id if node not exist

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I use generate-id() if the key node does not exist? Below I have an example of input XML and my transformation, but if the key node (StockItem/Master/Sups/Sup/Addr_ID) does not exist, the data will not be fed to the output file.
I need them there.

Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Stock>
    <StockItem>
      <Master_ID>dfdbc8b0-b58a-45f8-a7ad-418802eb2045</Master_ID>
      <Name>Alu brzda tlumič</Name>
      <Master ID="dfdbc8b0-b58a-45f8-a7ad-418802eb2045">
        <Sups>
          <Sup>
            <Addr_ID>6898e66a-5315-4933-9895-a226bbec8aad</Addr_ID>
            <Addr_Name>D-HOLZ , s.r.o.</Addr_Name>
          </Sup>
        </Sups>
      </Master>
      <Status>
            <Amount>14.0000</Amount>
      </Status>
    </StockItem>

    <StockItem>
      <Master_ID>30f2e859-c7b1-4e04-accd-9921cdd1a6ed</Master_ID>
      <Name>Alu profil Wenus </Name>
      <Master ID="30f2e859-c7b1-4e04-accd-9921cdd1a6ed">
        <Sups>
          <Sup>
            <Addr_ID>6898e66a-5315-4933-9895-a226bbec8aad</Addr_ID>
            <Addr_Name>D-HOLZ , s.r.o.</Addr_Name>
          </Sup>
        </Sups>
      </Master>
      <Status>
            <Amount>59.0000</Amount>
      </Status>
    </StockItem>

    <StockItem>
      <Master_ID>9ba2042f-c88a-4b13-99d2-e0e248d940b0</Master_ID>
      <Name>ANTARO 30 kg </Name>
      <Master ID="9ba2042f-c88a-4b13-99d2-e0e248d940b0">
        <Sups/>
      </Master>
      <Status>
            <Amount>0.0000</Amount>
      </Status>
    </StockItem>
    <StockItem>
      <Master_ID>69cbf3bb-a116-46dd-9ea3-9e0601fe75c6</Master_ID>
      <Name>lišta úchytková</Name>
      <Master ID="69cbf3bb-a116-46dd-9ea3-9e0601fe75c6">
        <Sups/>
      </Master>
      <Status>
            <Amount>1.0000</Amount>
      </Status>
    </StockItem>
  </Stock>
</Data>
```

my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="adr" match="Addr_ID" use="text()" />

<xsl:template match="Data">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Stock"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Stock">
    <xsl:element name="SortData">
    <xsl:for-each select="StockItem/Master/Sups/Sup/Addr_ID[generate-id() = generate-id(key('adr',.))]">

    <xsl:element name="Sup">
      <Addr_ID>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </Addr_ID>

       <xsl:for-each select="key('adr',.)">

            <xsl:element name ="Item">
              <xsl:element name ="Master_ID">
                <xsl:value-of select="../../../@ID"/>
              </xsl:element>

              <xsl:element name ="Amount" >
                <xsl:value-of select="../../../../Status/Amount"/>
              </xsl:element>

            </xsl:element>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        
      </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output si:

```
<SortData>
 <Sup>
  <Addr_ID>6898e66a-5315-4933-9895-a226bbec8aad</Addr_ID>
  <Item>
   <Master_ID>dfdbc8b0-b58a-45f8-a7ad-418802eb2045</Master_ID>
   <Amount>14.0000</Amount>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <Master_ID>30f2e859-c7b1-4e04-accd-9921cdd1a6ed</Master_ID>
   <Amount>59.0000</Amount>
  </Item>
 </Sup>
</SortData>
```

But desired output is:

```
<SortData>
   <Sup>
      <Addr_ID>6898e66a-5315-4933-9895-a226bbec8aad</Addr_ID>
      <Item>
         <Master_ID>dfdbc8b0-b58a-45f8-a7ad-418802eb2045</Master_ID>
         <Amount>14.0000</Amount>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Master_ID>30f2e859-c7b1-4e04-accd-9921cdd1a6ed</Master_ID>
         <Amount>59.0000</Amount>
      </Item>
   </Sup>

<!-- This part is missing in my output-->
   <Sup>
      <Addr_ID />
      <!-- or <Addr_ID>none</Addr_ID-->
      <Item>
         <Master_ID>9ba2042f-c88a-4b13-99d2-e0e248d940b0</Master_ID>
         <Amount>0.0000</Amount>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Master_ID>69cbf3bb-a116-46dd-9ea3-9e0601fe75c6</Master_ID>
         <Amount>1.0000</Amount>
      </Item>
   </Sup>
</SortData>
```

Comment: "Existence is not a predicate" as Immanuel Kant said. Don't speak of "a node that doesn't exist", speak of a condition that isn't satisfied by any node. Then go back to describe the problem you are trying to solve (which appears to be grouping), not the blind alley you have gone down in trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT you want to group the master items by `Addr_ID` in `Sup` - which may or may not exist.

This could be done as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="adr" match="Master" use="string(Sups/Sup/Addr_ID)" />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <SortData>
        <xsl:for-each select="Stock/StockItem/Master[generate-id() = generate-id(key('adr', string(Sups/Sup/Addr_ID)))]">
            <Sup>
                <Addr_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Sups/Sup/Addr_ID"/>
                </Addr_ID>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('adr', string(Sups/Sup/Addr_ID))">
                    <Item>
                        <Master_ID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                        </Master_ID>
                        <Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../Status/Amount"/>
                        </Amount>
                    </Item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Sup>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </SortData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes each `Master` has at most one `Sup` - while your structure allows for multiple occurrences of `Sup` in each `Master`.

Comment: Thank you. This really solves my problem, although the structure allows more records, but it is never used.